# Ruby on Rails timezone storing different timezones to datetime attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, timezone, oracle12c, rhel6

I have a model "Request", that have the common attributes created_at and updated_at, but have others datetime attributes: "inserted_at" and "response_deadline". My problem is especially with response_deadline, that sometimes is stored with the correct timezone and other times with a different one (wtf??), and in other cases, response_deadline with the same timezone's giving a correct datetime and the other a wrong datetime.

My application.rb is configured with the correct timezone:

`config.time_zone = 'Brasilia'`

and I already tried change the AR default timezone:

`config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc or :local`

- Other problem is that if I put `:local` the problem in response_deadline is solved, but the other datetime attributes get wrong.
- The server timezone and date are correct too.

Sometimes the response_deadline is stored like that:

`response_deadline: "2018-11-01 02:00:00"` - WRONG

and other like that:

`response_deadline: "2018-11-01 03:00:00"` - CORRECT

And the strangiest behavior, two apparently wrong timezones:

`response_deadline: "2018-11-09 02:00:00"` - WRONG

`response_deadline: "2018-10-30 02:00:00"` - CORRECT?

but when I run in rails c:

`2.3.0 :002 > request1.response_deadline
 => Thu, 08 Nov 2018 23:00:00 -03 -03:00`

`2.3.0 :002 > request2.response_deadline
 => Tue, 30 Out 2018 00:00:00 -02 -02:00`

- The data are taken from a CSV file (uploaded), and the response_deadline has this format:

`29/10/2018 23:59:59`

Controller snippet:

```
uploaded_file = params[:file]
unsaved = []
begin
  sheet = RubyXL::Parser.parse(uploaded_file.tempfile.path)
  dados = sheet[0]

  demandas = []
  (4...(dados.sheet_data.rows.size - 1)).each do |num|
    if !dados.sheet_data.rows[num][1].nil?

      request_type = RequestType.has_request_type? dados.sheet_data.rows[num][3].value,Request.sources[:ouv]

      demanda = {
        protocol: dados.sheet_data.rows[num][2].value,
        source_cd: Request.sources[:ouv],
        request_type_id: request_type,
        created_at: dados.sheet_data.rows[num][7].value,
        inserted_at: Time.now,
        response_deadline: dados.sheet_data.rows[num][8].value,
        requester_name: dados.sheet_data.rows[num][21].value.blank? ? "Anônimo" : dados.sheet_data.rows[num][21].value,
        hide_requester_information: nil,
        all_completed_information: false
      }
      demandas << demanda
    end
  end
  count = 0
  demandas.each_with_index do |demanda, index|
    request = Request.new(demanda)
    request.requester = Requester.where(name: "eouv").take
    if request.valid? && !request.request_type_id.nil?
      if request.save
     ...
```

Why?? I really wanna understand what is happening... =/

- All the attributes are datetime, including `:response_deadline` of course.

**Environment:**

- This is happen only in the production enviroment, the DB is Oracle 12c, running on a RHEL 6.
- Ruby 2.3.0 and Rails 4.2.1

*Someone could help to try indetify what is going on?*

ps:some days ago this was not happening.

Comment: Please add context: explain where these dates are taken from to be saved to the database. Typed by user? Then show form and controller

Comment: I updated the question with a controller snippet...